# How to send JavaScript collection to PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send data from form to PHP file using JavaScript. PHP file pushes this data to database. For now, almost all works well but I have a problem with array from `getElementsByClassName`. After sending to database I can see only "Array" but no values of this array.

Here's a JS:

```
function przekaz_form($wejscie) {
    var datas = document.formularz.datas.value;
    var klient = document.formularz.firma.value;
    var comment = document.formularz.comment.value;
    var collect = document.getElementsByClassName($wejscie);      
    var datan = document.formularz.datan.value;

    var items = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < collect.length; i++) {
        items.push(collect.item(i).value);
    }


    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'addtobase.php',
        type: 'post',
        data:{
            devices: items,
            datas: datas,
            klient: klient,
            comment: comment,
            datan: datan 
        },
        success: function(output) {
          alert('Success');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but I'd use `items.push(collect[i].value);` instead. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9y5rf5yg/1/).

Comment: You are probably using `echo $array` instead of `print_r($array)`. You can't echo arrays using the `echo` command.

Comment: what do you get in `items` for, if you don't use them in the code you showed

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
$inputData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Once you have the $inputData variable you can access the data in the JSON by:

```
$devices = (!is_null($inputData) && property_exists($inputData, "devices")) ? strip_tags($inputData->{"devices"}) : 0;
```

You should also try to better format the JSON : http://json.org/example

Comment: *You need* implies that this is the only solution. Is it?